# Why my image created by php is not displaying?

Tags: php

I have a problem , I have a software that gets pc tech specs and post them online and we are offering a signature image for each specs, this is created by php , but is not working anymore;
Demo link : http://checkmyspecs.co.uk/button.php?id=646725 or go to any specs page , example : http://www.checkmyspecs.co.uk/display2.php?id=646725 and down on the page is grab button code.

The image must be created by button.php , here is the code :

```
<?php

include "db.php"; 

function getdata($viewerid) { 
$query = "SELECT * FROM data where viewerid = '$viewerid'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$data = array(); 
array_push($data,$row['bootmethod'],$row['ComputerCaption'],$row['Infrared'],$row['DayLight'],$row['ManufacturerBox'],$row['Model'],$row['cores'],$row['memory'],$row['monitor'],$row['resolution'],$row['pixels'],$row['cpuvoltage'],$row['clockspeed'],$row['AddressWidth'],$row['SocketDesignation'],$row['cpuname'],$row['loadpercent'],$row['applications'],$row['videocardname'],$row['refreshrate'],$row['videodriver'],$row['installed'],$row['hddata'],$row['directx']); 
return $data; 
} 


function LoadPNG($imgname,$cur)
{

$getvalues = getdata($cur);

/* Attempt to open */
$im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);
// Removes white background (made from the original transparency)
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
// Make the background transparent

//Generate the text to write onto the image (the php Version).
//Don't know much about this


// Add some shadow to the text

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 173, 238);
$darkblue = imagecolorallocate($im, 54, 154, 191);



$font = '/fonts/arialbd.ttf';

$ramo = $getvalues[7];
$cpuo = $getvalues[15];
$gpuo = $getvalues[18];
$screeno = $getvalues[9];

$ram = "$ramo MB"; 
$cpu = "$cpuo"; 
$gpu = "$gpuo "; 
$screen = "$screeno"; 

imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 40, 23, $black, $font, $cpu);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 40, 53, $black, $font, $gpu);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 40, 83, $black, $font, $screen);
imagettftext($im, 11, 0, 40, 113, $black, $font, $ram);


// write text
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 3, 0);
return $im;
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$button = '/images/button.png'; 
$img = LoadPNG($button,$_GET['id']);
imagepng($img); 


?>
```

Comment: "but is not working anymore" is a poor description to give to anyone trying to help.

Comment: Change the content-type to text/plain and then see if you can spot what's causing the error.

Comment: be careful: your code is straight SQL injectable and you just supplied attackers with the link. Always distrust all outside data and use prepared statements. Consider using pdo: http://be2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

Your image isn't an image.  Here's what is really being output:

> **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **24**
>   
>   **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **33**
>   
>   **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **34**
>   
>   **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **35**
>   
>   **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **36**
>   
>   **Warning**:  imagecolorallocate(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **37**
>   
>   **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function imagettftext() in **/home/checkmys/public_html/button.php** on line **53**

You can use tools such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see this, even when your content-type is set as an image.  If you would remove that `@` symbol, we could see the error describing why your image could not be created.

Also, you are currently wide open to SQL injection.  You should use [prepared queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) to avoid this problem.